RecurrenceTable vs For loop : they do not give the same results. Why?
I have a second-order recurrence equation that I want to plot.
I've used two different methods.
The first uses RecurrenceTable, the second uses a traditional For loop.
The two don't give the same answer. It's the For loop that gives the right result. Why does RecurrenceTable fail?
My code:
Clear["Global`*"];

a0 = 1; a1 = 2; a2 = 1;
b0 = 1; b1 = -1.8; b2 = 0.81;

sol = RecurrenceTable[
   Reduce[{x[n + 2] == x[n + 1], 
     y[n + 2] == 
      a0 x[n + 2] + a1 x[n + 1] + a2 x[n] - b0 y[n + 2] - 
       b1 y[n + 1] - b2 y[n], x[0] == 1, y[0] == 0, 
     y[1] == 1}, {x[n + 2], y[n + 2]}], y, {n, 0, 100}, 
   DependentVariables -> {x, y}];

ListPlot[sol, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Full]

capN = 100; (*N is a predefined MMA function so use capN instead*)
x = Table[1, {capN}];
y = Table[0, {capN}];
For[n = 3, n <= capN, n++, 
 y[[n]] = a0*x[[n]] + a1*x[[n - 1]] + a2*x[[n - 2]] - 
          b0*y[[n]] - b1*y[[n - 1]] - b2*y[[n - 2]]]

ListPlot[y, Joined -> True] 


Clear[yy]

a0 = 1; a1 = 2; a2 = 1; b0 = 1; b1 = -1.8; b2 = 0.81;
nn = 100;
x = Table[1, nn];
y = Table[0, nn];

Do[y[[n]] = 
  a0*x[[n]] + a1*x[[n - 1]] + a2*x[[n - 2]] - b0*y[[n]] - 
   b1*y[[n - 1]] - b2*y[[n - 2]], {n, 3, nn}]

y == RecurrenceTable[{yy[1] == 0, yy[2] == 0, 
   yy[n] == a0 + a1 + a2 - b1*yy[n - 1] - b2*yy[n - 2]}, 
  yy, {n, 1, nn}]

ListLinePlot[
 RecurrenceTable[{yy[1] == 0, yy[2] == 0, 
   yy[n] == a0 + a1 + a2 - b1*yy[n - 1] - b2*yy[n - 2]}, 
  yy, {n, 1, nn}]]


True



Thank you very much, azerbajdzan.

In fact, there is a mistake in the recurrence equations. The good ones are :
 y[[n]] = (a0/b0)*x[[n]] + (a1/b0))*x[[n - 1]] + (a2/b0)*x[[n - 2]] - (b1/b0)*y[[n - 1]] - (b2//b0)*y[[n - 2]]]

and
y[n + 2] == 
      (a0/b0)  x[n + 2] + (a1b0  x[n + 1] + (a2/b0)  x[n] - 
       (b1b0) y[n + 1] - (b2b0) y[n]


@Pascal77 It is your mistake not mine. My post correctly answers your question with the original equation.

yes, you are right. It is my mistake and your answer was very relevant. Thank you again.

…It's because Set (=) and Equal (==) are different.
As mentioned in the document of RecurrenceTable:

RecurrenceTable[eqns, expr, {n, nmax}] generates a list of values of expr for successive n based on solving the recurrence equations eqns.

But y[[n]] = a0*x[[n]] + a1*x[[n - 1]] + a2*x[[n - 2]] - b0*y[[n]] - b1*y[[n - 1]] - b2*y[[n - 2]]] is not a recurrence equation. Why? Because both sides involve y[[n]], and the y[[n]] will be overwritten based on the old y[[0]] in the calculation. A much simpler example showing the same issue:
y = 123;
y = y + 1
(* 124 *)
y == y + 1
(* False *)

"OK, then how to fix the code? " It can be fixed in various manner of course, one possible solution is:
Clear[x, y, n]

yold[n_] = 0;
x[n_] = 1;

sys = {y[n + 2] == a0  x[n + 2] + a1  x[n + 1] + a2  x[n] - 
                   b0  yold[n + 2] - b1  y[n + 1] - b2  y[n], 
       y[0] == 0, y[1] == 0};

RecurrenceTable[sys, y, {n, 0, 100}] // ListPlot



Thank you very much for your answer, xzczd.
In fact, there is a mistake in the recurrence equation. The good one is the following one : y(n)=(a0/b0)*x(n)+(a1/b0)*x(n-1)+(a2/b0)*x(n-2)-(b1/b0)*y(n-1)-(b2/b0)*y(n-2).
